# OutOfMemoryError: When to "Dump HPROF file"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have some kind of memory problem with my game app. When I run it for the first time, the splash screen activity works, the level selection activity works, then the game playing mode works and I can play through many levels without problem. Then I quit the game. Then the second time I run the app I get an OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget even before I see the splash screen.

My app is based on a single Application called SD_globals like so:

```
public class SD_Globals extends Application
{
    int example_global_data = 99;
    // stuff
}
```

and five separate activities, each of which has access to a variety of global data declared in SD_Globals. One of the activities for example is SD_gameplay like so:

```
public class SD_GamePlay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    SD_Globals gs; // gs stands for global state

    gs = ((SD_Globals)getApplicationContext());

    // now I can access global variable using code like this:
    int x = gs.example_global_data;
}
```

Any ideas about what kinds of errors could be occurring with this setup would be welcome - though that's not my specific question.

I have read a little about using DDMS and the memory analyser to help diagnose problems, but one thing I am unclear about is what is the best time to press the "Dump HPROF file" button in order to get the most useful information. Should it be while my game is still in-play or, after I have exited it (but before the second running) or just after the crash?

**EDIT:** In response to Akhil's answer, I shall just clarify that I use getApplicationContext() exactly once in the onCreate method of each separate activity and in no other instances. I should also say that this general application structure (with `gs = ((SD_Globals)getApplicationContext())`) has been working perfectly robustly in an older version of my game which has been on the market for several weeks now and has had 30,000 downloads and zero OutOfMemoryError's reported back to Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use getApplicationContext() unless you are sure it is needed. It is making ur assets application scoped and they are not getting recycled. Stick to the narrowest context you can provide like an Activity's.Change all its occurences.

Since it is a game , I am assuming you are using bitmaps. are you **recycling** them when the activity they are a part of is being destroyed ( make sure you are using the activity as the context and not the whole application).

You *will* need to dump the heap from hprof time to time in regular intervals(maybe 2-3 per activity).So that you could see the cause of memory leaks as you are spending time with you app by **comparing** heaps which are some time apart.

This is the general answer I could provide as the question is theoretical.

Comment: "Never use getApplicationContext()"- wow, I thought that this was a (semi) standard way in which to keep a set of global data alive throughout an application. Are you suggesting that I'm not allowed to keep some global data accessible throughout an application?

Comment: @Mick : I have said use it only when you need it. If you want some global data, sure you can use it. Though Not advisible to use this for all kinds of data if one doesnt need them to globally accessible. I have seen people using it the wrong way, so just wanted to point it out .

Comment: Ok, point taken. And thank you for your answer. But one final thing; sometimes the memory leak can reveal itself within a single HPROF snapshot - given my circumstances, what time would you suspect was best if restricted to just one?

Comment: maybe the time you are about to exit your game. WHat do you think?